# bash iterate through several directories to build one single yaml file

Tags: bash, yaml

I have a directory with several folders (only interested in folders one level deep) and each one of these folders have files inside (values.yaml and example.yaml)

```
folder_1
 -values.yaml
 -example.yaml

folder_2
 -values.yaml
 -example.yaml
...
```

values.yaml is a valid yaml file with several values

example of values.yaml for folder 1

```
name: John
age: 66
country:
  name: Spain
  lenght: 32
...
```

example of values.yaml for folder 2

```
name: Simon
age: 90
country:
  name: France
  lenght: 33
...
```

I have to iterate through every single one of these directories and build an yaml file where I put the folder name concatenated with a certain string (eg:-batch) and put all values from values.yaml from this folder inside this field

Example of final output

```
folder_1-batch
  name: John
  age: 66
  country
    name:Spain
    lenght: 32
  ...

folder_2-batch
  name: Simon
  age: 90
  country:
    name: France
    lenght: 33
  ...
```

Any ideia how I could do this? I am able to copy all the content from every single values.yaml to a new file, but I am not understanding how I can put this content inside the main field (folder concatenated with -batch) with the correct indentation of a yaml file

---

small update: folders can have any name, and do not follow any pattern (folder_1 and folder_2 was just an example)

Comment: Your expected output does not seem to be valid YAML. There are missing colons, and each colon after a key needs a space after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

```bash
shopt -s nullglob
for pathname in */values.yaml; do
    yq -y --arg name "${pathname%/*}-batch" '{ ($name): . }' "$pathname"
done >output.yaml
```

This first enables `nullglob` to avoid running the subsequent loop at all if there are no matching names.

The loop iterates over all `values.yaml` files in all the 1st-level subdirectories of the current directory.

For each file, `yq` is called to merge in the file's contents under the key given by the internal variable `$name`, which gets its value from `--arg` on the command line.  The variable's value will be the directory's name followed by the string `-batch`.

All output is written to the file `output.yaml`.

Testing:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── folder1
│   └── values.yaml
└── folder2
    └── values.yaml

2 directories, 2 files
```

```bash
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for pathname in */values.yaml; do yq -y --arg name "${pathname%/*}-batch" '{ ($name): . }' "$pathname"; done >output.yaml
```

```bash
$ cat output.yaml
folder1-batch:
  name: John
  age: 66
  country:
    name: Spain
    lenght: 32
folder2-batch:
  name: Simon
  age: 90
  country:
    name: France
    lenght: 33
```

Comment: Hey @Kusalananda. Can the same be achieved with  mikefarah's tool ?

Comment: @AndreSilva The issue with Mike's `yq` is that I haven't found an obvious way to safely import the value of a shell variable into an expression, i.e., an equivalent to Andrey's `--arg key value` option.  This way of importing a value ensures that the imported string is properly JSON-encoded.

Comment: @AndreSilva You could possibly just inject the shell variable into `yq eval "{ \"${pathname%/*}-batch\": . }" "$pathname"` (or something similar, this is untested), but that would break as soon as any pathname contained a character that needs special JSON encoding, so I won't include that into my answer.

Comment: Understood. Thankyou @Kusalananda

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the folders, use `sed` to indent each YAML file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for d in folder_* ; do
    echo "$d"-batch
    sed 's/^/  /' "$d"/values.yaml
done > output.yaml
```

Comment: Hey @choroba. This goes well only for the first element of the iteration, but not for the remaining ones

Comment: @AndreSilva: Please provide more details. What's wrong with the second or third iteration?

Comment: second folder name is written right after the last value of the first folder 

```code
folder_1-batch:
  name: John
  age: 66
  country
    name:Spain
    lenght: 32folder_2-batch
```

Comment: @AndreSilva: So add an `echo` after the `sed` line.

Comment: Hey @choroba yes, I already did it. Thank you.